# VBA Macro that sorts a column having multiple dates old date to new dates

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA Macro. I am trying to create a macro that sorts the column named "Vessel Estimated Time of Departure"! This column has multiple dates in it in format MM-DD-YYYY format. All I want is my macro to sort this particular column starting from old/past dates first to new/future date at last.
I have tried coding in many ways but nothing works out. Below is my code and excel screenshot for ref.

My Code: -

```
Sub Date_Sort()

'Vessel Estimated Time of Departure
Dim wb As Workbook

Dim fRng As Range

Dim tRow As Long
Dim fCol As Long


    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Set fRng = wb.Sheets("Main").Rows(1).Find(what:="Vessel Estimated Time of Departure", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
    fCol = fRng.Column
    
    tRow = wb.Sheets("Main").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    With Range("fRng" & tRow)
    .Sort key1:=.Cells(1), order1:=xlDescending, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
    End With
    
End Sub
```

I am getting an error in "With Statement".

> Error code 1004 Method Object global failed...

Excel ScreenShot
[image: Excel ScreenShot Vessel Estimated Time of Departure]

I want the macro to sort the data based on the column "Vessel Estimated Time of Departure" in this particular column there are only dates (Date format "MM-DD-YYYY") and few blank cells. So macro should sort the date from old to new then after new dates all data with blank cells.

Comment: What do you think Range("fRng" & tRow) refers to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is with `Range("fRng" & tRow)`. If you build that range address you will see that it is invalid. If your last row is 20 you will get `V1:20` which of course is a invalid range.

---

Correcting for that issue and changing up the variables to simplify you end up with something like...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sorter()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Target As Range, lr As Long

Set Target = ws.Rows(1).Find("Vessel Estimated Time of Departure")
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Target.Column).End(xlUp).Row

Target.Resize(lr, 1).Sort key1: = Target.Offset(1), order1:= xlDescending, Header:= xlYes

End Sub
```